# change image on id after succes:

Tags: image, src, attr

I have this piece of code, but can't seem to get it working.

success: function(){
$('.like').find('.like'+like_id).attr("src", "/img/icons/checked.gif");
...etc.

.like is the class for all the images. OnClick I would like to have the img + id changed. It keeps changing all the images with class .like.

Even when using this, it is passing the right ID, but still changing all the .like images instead of the one with the right id:
var value = $(this).attr ( "id" );

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you wanna add which language you are refering to (javascript?) and what else you are using (jQuery?). Than you might want to add the html code so one can try to reproduce your problem. All I can say: If your image has the class 'like like10' and the id 10 gets called, it should work.

Comment: Sorry, Boo, it is jquery.
I user alerts to give me if the right ID is passed, and it is.

Comment: and the html is:
<img src"" class="like" id=\"unique nr\">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that with find('.like'+like_id) you are finding every item that has the class like10 (for like_id 10). what you want is `$('#'+like_id).attr();`. What you want to consider is that an id must be unique within the whole html element, so using only the unqiue_id as id is not the best way. A better way would be `<img src="" class="like" id="like1">` and then using `$('#like'+like_id).attr();`

So, you're code could look like this:

```
success: function(){
  $('#like' + like_id).attr("src", "/img/icons/checked.gif");
  ...
}

<img src"" class="like" id="like{unique nr}">
```

Comment: Forgot to thank you for this help, Boo. This worked perfectly!